# solution to heat equation

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

We have the follwing PDE:

$$
\frac{\partial W}{\partial \tau} =
{1 \over 2}\sigma^{2}\,
\frac{\partial^{2} W}{\partial^{2}x}\quad
\mbox{where}\quad 
x = \epsilon +
\left(r - {1 \over 2}\sigma^{2}\right)\tau
$$
We look for a solution of the following form:

$W(x,\tau)=\tau^af((x-c)/\tau^b)$

We have

$\mu=(x-c)/\tau^b$

We want to ensure that the special solution has the property that its integral over all
$\epsilon$ is independent of $\tau$. To ensure that we require that

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \tau^af((x-c)/\tau^b)dx$

is a constant. The part that I don't understand is how you get to the next step which is

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \tau^{a+b}f(\mu)d\mu$

Comment: there's no epsilon to begin with? also you may want to consider change of variables $\mu = (x-c)/\tau^b$

Answer (score 1):

It is just a change of variables. Let $\mu = \frac{x-c}{\tau^b}$. As $x \to \infty$, $\mu \to \infty$, and as $x \to -\infty$, $\mu \to -\infty$. Moreover, $$\frac{d\mu}{d x} = \tau^{-b}. $$ Hence, \begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \tau^a f \big ( \tau^{-b}(x-c)\big ) dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \tau^a f (\mu  )  \frac{d x}{d \mu}d\mu 
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \tau^{a+b} f (\mu  )  d\mu . 
\end{align*}